# Wordpress relationship loop in <head>

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a page which echos about 10 items. I would like them all to have a different background image on hover.

I'm guessing I would need to have my loop in my `<head>` tag so that I can apply a background image.

Here is my loop:

```
<?php 
    // get background images for the services page
    $post = get_field('related_services');
        if( $posts ): ?>

            <style>

                <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
                    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

                        .sector-box[style]::after {
                            background-image: url("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/creative-bg-hover.jpg");   
                            color:#<?php the_field( 'colour' ); ?>;
                        }

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </style>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I can't get it to echo a style for each..

Would I also need to apply an ID to each box? So that it knows which box to apply the background image to?

here is my html:

```
<?php 
            $posts = get_field('related_services');
            if( $posts ): ?>

                <div class="container">

                    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
                    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

                        <div class="sector-box reveal" style="background-color:<?php the_field( 'colour' ); ?>;">
                            <div class="sector-title">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title( '' ); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Close Single Service box-->

                    <?php endforeach; ?>

            </div> 

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!--Close Service Sector Boxes-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>
<?php echo get_the_title( $post->ID ); ?>
<?php echo get_field('colour', $post->ID ); ?>
```

and remove function

```
<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "Use the following" and "remove function"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.